# Are dependent variables necessarily functions of one another?

Tags: function, dependent-variable

### The problem

Suppose you have two variables $X_1,X_2$ so that $X_1\not\perp\!\!\!\!\! \perp X_2$.

Do we **necessarily** have that a functional relationship exists between them?

I am assuming random variables are the usual real valued measurable functions, and if that helps one can assume every variable has a density and the conditional densities exist.

I am interested in potential transforms $f\colon\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ which act on the realisations of one variable (say $X_2$) to (potentially nondeterministically) give the other (say $X_1$).

I am ruling out the cases of confounding and conditioning on colliders.

Formally, do we have that dependence necessarily implies $\exists f,Z\;$ so that $X_1 = f(X_2,Z)$ and either $Z\perp\!\!\! \perp X_2$ or $Z\perp\!\!\! \perp X_1$ .

$Z$ should be interpreted as a disturbance term responsible for the non-deterministic nature of the mapping.

Obviously, I want the function $f$ to be so that $f(x,\cdot)\neq f(x',\cdot)$ for some $x,x'\in \text{Supp}(X_2)$. Intuitively I'm interested in describing $X_1$ as the result of a non-deterministic mapping of $X_2$.

Further, I assume for now that a variable that has the same marginal distribution as $X_1$ and the same joint distribution with $X_2$ can be identified with $X_1$. The idea is "if it behaves the same, why make a distinction?".

### The motivation

I essentially would like some tools to justify working with models of the form $X_1 = f(X_2) + Z$ or in a more general case $X_1 = f(X_2,Z)$.

### Some ideas

One idea I can think of is the Renyi independence criterion: if $X_1,X_2$ are dependent then for some continuous functions $f,g$ we have $\text{Cov}_{X_1,X_2}(f(X_1),g(X_2))\neq 0$.
This implies that for a region of non-zero probability, $f(X_1) = \alpha g(X_2)+ \beta$.
However this doesn't help me further than this. Playing with inverse cdfs also doesn't really work as far as I'm concerned.

### Some examples

These include

1. additive noise $Z$ on top of some univariate function as $X_1=f(X_2)+Z$. Then $X_1\mid X_2$ is simply the distribution of $Z$ with an altered location $f(x_2)$
2. Multiplicative noise, for example @Dave 's answer: $X_1 = Z\cdot f(X_2)$. If $Z$ takes values $\{-1,1\}$ you do observe two curves, but they are described as a unique functional relationship

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = y$ and $Z=X_1$; this would seem to satisfy your conditions regardless of whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent or not.   Or am I missing something?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I am looking for a **necessary** condition. This means, do we have dependent IMPLIES functional relationship. I'll update my post though.

Comment: If X1 depends on X2, then I would argue that the (partial) derivative of X1 with respect to X2 by definition exists, is a function, and is nonzero over at least some subset of reals, so it seems to fit the bill. N.B. the dependency relation is not commutative though.

Comment: To take a derivative you need not only a function but a differentiable one at that! :)

Comment: I'm trying hard to figure what you mean and keep coming up short.  It looks your "variables" are (non-independent) random variables, which by definition means they are (measurable) functions $X_1,X_2:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}.$ Is this the definition you are working with? Why doesn't @jbowman's initial example completely resolve the issue?  Your two "NB" notes make no sense--perhaps some words are missing from each?

Comment: In your paragraph starting "formally", you refer to $X_1 = f(X_2,Z)$, but in the next paragraph you are using "equals in distribution", which is not at all the same thing.  Then in the following paragraph, you say "$X_1$ is not equal in distribution..."  What you actually mean is not at all clear.  Please delete the incorrect parts of your question rather than adding (more) contradictory text!

Comment: @jbowman's answer takes the equation 'too literally'. I am looking for a function which truly varies when X2 takes different values. This is an intuitive notion of "functional relationship". One could be pedantic and say "so that f changes if X2 takes at least 2 different values".

Comment: @whuber I am interested in situations where dependence structure can be expressed as a functional relationship. This means I have fixed joint distribution for (X1,X2) , fixed marginals and conditionals. However given that information, I wish to find a functional equation which gives rise to the whole structure. For example one can observe some cloud of dependent points like $f(X_2)+\epsilon= X_1$ only through the joint and marginal distributions and try to find the underlying $f$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edits differ from your comments.  Your comments suggest you seek to study the *conditional* distribution of $X_1$ on $X_2$ rather than the marginal distribution. The context you provide also suggests you are thinking of $Z$ as being independent of $X_2,$ for otherwise--as @jbowman has pointed out--the problem is trivial since one solution is $Z=X_1-X_2$ and $f(x,y)=x+y.$

Comment: The problem also is uninteresting when reinterpreted in terms of conditional distributions and equality of distribution. After all, writing $F_{x_2}$ for the conditional distribution of $X_1$ when $X_2=x_2,$ simply *define* $f(x_2,z) = F_{x_2}^{-1}(z)$ and let $Z$ independently have a uniform distribution on $[0,1].$ Then $(F(X_2,Z),X_2)$ equals $(X_1,X_2)$ in distribution. Perhaps these observations may help you refine your question further.

Comment: Yes, the independence of Z is necessary.

Comment: I will refine the question further in the upcoming days. Thank you for your contributions !

Comment: The equality in distribution you point out is precisely related to something I deleted earlier though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This question is interesting** because it concerns the general problem of *regression* in the sense of characterizing (or estimating based on data) the conditional distribution of one variable, $X_1,$ based on values of another variable $X_2.$  Their lack of statistical independence implies there is something to be gained from this.

---

We may take our cues from the theory of Generalized Linear Models (GLMs), which suppose the conditional distribution of $X_1$ is a member of a finitely parameterized family of distributions and the parameters depend first on a linear function of $X_2$ and, usually, by a nonlinear transformation of that result (aka the "link function").  In the present question no such parametric assumption is made.  We should therefore work with the conditional distribution of $X_1$ directly.

Suppose, then, that $X_2=x_2$ is a given value and that we can make sense of the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_2=x_2.$  Let this distribution function be $F_{x_2}.$  (For the moment, let's drop the $x_2$ subscript for brevity.)  By definition, for any number $x_1,$

$$\Pr(X_1 \le x_1\mid X_2=x_2) = F(x_1).$$

The axioms of probability imply $F$ has a right inverse $F^{-1}$ characterized by

$$F\left(F^{-1}(p)\right) = p$$

for all $0\lt p \lt 1.$

Let $Z$ be a random variable with a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1).$  This means that for all $0\le p\le 1,$ $\Pr(Z \le p) = p$.  Note that for any number $x,$

$$\Pr\left(F^{-1}(Z) \le x\right) = \Pr\left(F(F^{-1}(Z)) \le F(x)\right) = \Pr\left(Z \le F(x)\right) = F(x).$$

This shows that the distribution function of the random variable $F^{-1}(Z)$ is $F.$

Suppose it is possible to find such a uniform $Z$ that is independent of $X_2.$ (One can always do this by enlarging the original probability space if necessary.)  In this case the foregoing result holds for every possible value $x_2.$  Consequently, if we *define* the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ by

> $$f(x_2, z) = F_{x_2}^{-1}(z),$$

then $(f(X_2,Z), X_2)$ is a bivariate random variable for which

1. Its second component, $X_2,$ is identical to the second component of the original variable $(X_1,X_2);$ and
2. The conditional distribution of its first component equals the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_2.$

Consequently,

> The random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(f(X_2,Z), X_2)$ are equal in distribution.

*A fortiori,* $f(X_2,Z)$ and $X_1$ are equal in distribution.

---

#### Examples

**As the first example, consider the intriguing illustration** presented in the reply by Dave at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/443150/919/.  It displays a $42$-element dataset consisting of a sequence of ordered pairs

$$(x_1,x_2) = (i/10, \pm i/10)$$

as $i$ ranges from $-20$ to $20$ inclusive.  (The value $(0,0)$ is included twice, even though that is not apparent from the scatterplot.)  We may conceive of this in terms of its empirical distribution, which assigns the probability $1/42$ to each element of the dataset, thereby defining a bivariate random variable $(X_1,X_2).$

In this case we will need to define $F_{x_2}$ for each value $x_2$ that appears as a second coordinate in the dataset (it doesn't matter how we define $F_{x_2}$ elsewhere, because those values have no probability). With this in mind, compute

$$F_{i}(x) = \left\{\matrix{0 & x \lt -|i| \\ 1/2 & -|i| \le x \lt |i| \\ 1 & \text{otherwise}}\right.$$

for any number $i.$  One right inverse of $F_{i}$ maps the interval $[0,1/2]$ to  $-|i|$ and the interval $(1/2,1]$ to $|i|.$  You can see this implemented in the code below.

The claim is that

> the distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$ is the same as that of $(F_{X_2}^{-1}(Z), X_2).$

Rather than do a direct calculation, let's have the computer simulate the latter using `R`, to be compared to the scatterplot of $(X_1, X_2)$ in Dave's reply:

```R
set.seed(17)
n <- 1e5                                                  # Simulation size
f <- function(i, p) ifelse (p <= 1/2, -1, 1) * abs(i)     # Inverse conditional distribution
X.2 <- sample((-20):20 / 10, n, replace=TRUE)             # Sample of X[2]
Z <- runif(n)                                             # Independent sample of Z
X.1 <- f(X.2, Z)                                          # Construction of X[1]
```

**This scatterplot confirms it works correctly:**

[image: Figure]

Another example suggested in comments is a uniform distribution on a circle:

[image: Figure 2]

Generating these data required only two changes to the code: $(1+X_2)/2$ has a Beta$(1/2,1/2)$ distribution and $F^{-1}$ now reflects the equation of the circle:

```R
X.2 <- rbeta(n, 1/2, 1/2) * 2 - 1
F.inv <- function(p, i) ifelse (p <= 1/2, -1, 1) * sqrt(1 - i^2)
```

Finally, **the more difficult situations occur when the scatterplot cannot be conceived of as exhibiting either of the $X_i$ as a function of the other,** as in this uniform distribution on a square:

[image: Figure 3]

Here, the marginal distribution of $X_2$ is a mixture of a uniform distribution on the interval $[-1,1]$ and equal point masses at $\pm 1,$ which can be simulated via

```R
X.2 <- pmax(-1, pmin(1, runif(n, -2, 2)))
```

The function $F^{-1}_{i}$ depends on whether its argument is in the interval $(-1,1)$ or equal to $\pm1;$ it can be implemented as

```R
F.inv <- function(p, i) ifelse (abs(i)==1, 2*p - 1, ifelse (p <= 1/2, -1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer on using inverse Conditional CDFs! :). Although I briefly mentioned this before, your answer gives all the context and examples; wonderful!

Comment: I am not familiar enough with probability theory to know why one needs to specify that the two variables induce a conditional probability that is distributed as X1|X2, could you have some reference/short explanation against simply stating: "By the universal transform theorem Finv(Z|x2) is distributed as X1|X2"?

Comment: Also would you know about some "model selection" justification that would give proper justification for building the relationship one way (X1=f(X2,Z)) rather than the other (X2=f(X1,Z')) ? This might be worth another question though.

Comment: I haven't invoked any "universal transform theorem;" indeed, I have avoided using anything other than definitions and [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms).  The "model selection problem" is a matter of what the underlying statistical question might be: it's not something to be decided mathematically.  In brief, do you wish to characterize $X_1$ in terms of $X_2$ or *vice versa?*

Comment: What I call "universal transform theorem" can be deduced from the axioms of probability; I was rather asking whether this specific theorem was valid in this context!

Comment: Also; your answer about model selection doesn't quite convince me. In regression, we often have to choose between different basis functions, or different degrees for polynomials; how come we have derived heuristics about this type of choice, and simply not the choice of whether it is more appropriate to regress in one direction and not the other? This question however is probably related to Bayesian networks and "graph" interpretations of probability

Comment: There are a huge number of discussions here of what variables to choose for regression and how to do so--please search our site.  I don't know what you mean by "this specific theorem," because neither you nor I have cited one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good place to use a picture.

```
x0 <- x1 <- seq(-2,2,0.1)
y0 <- x0
y1 <- -x1
x <- c(x0,x1)
y <- c(y0,y1)
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

I think the lack of independence is evident. However, the relationship cannot be functional, as a large value of $X1$, say $X1=2$, results in either $X2=2$ or $X2=-2$, and there's the usual business about a function having a unique output for each input.

(I considered that we could call it functional if we see the output as the vector $[-2,2]$ or the set $\{-2,2\}$, but I don't think those work. The relationship is to select one of those values, not a vector of possible values or the entire set of possible values.)

Comment: To me this is functional. Let Z be a binary noise variable with values {-1,1} , then f(X1,Z) = Z*X1 is what you gave. You can view this as multiplicative binary noise.

Comment: @user715586 What if the points were in a circle instead of an X?

Comment: Then you could invert $X_1^2+X_2^2=1$ wherever it is defined

Comment: However the circle is a good edge case. I am not sure how to handle this situation if the relationship is noisy.

Answer (score 0):

In common factor models, observed variables dependent on the same common factor covary and yet are conditionally independent given the common factor upon which they are jointly dependent. In the literature on graphical causal models, this structure--two variables jointly dependent on a third variable but with no relation between themselves--identifies the third variable as a "confounder," because it produces covariance between variables without a causal relation (see [Felix Elwert's](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.364.7505&rep=rep1&type=pdf) very nice introduction).

Alternatively, the two variables may be causes of a third variable.  This marks the third variable as a "collider." Here, conditioning on the third variable (which is a mistake) *creates* a dependency between the first two, even though there is no functional relation between them.

Comment: While this is a **very good** answer, I forgot to mention that I'm in the case where no collider or confounder exists! I'll update the post again ...

Comment: Well then, aside from the roads, public safety, education, wine...there could still be spurious endogeneity due to an undiagnosed selection problem, if X1 and X2 are treatment and outcome variables in an experiment. Selection might happen by dropout or through noncompliance with the treatment regimen.

Comment: I assume endogeneity refers to potential paths which are unnacounted for in the model (you don't account for some latent cause of X1, but this cause also depends on X2). This is not a theoretical problem at all, since the two paths combine nicely into a single functional equation (more complex though)...