# How can I show that the entropy of a function of random variables cannot be greater than their joint entropy?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

Given the discrete random variables $X,Y,$ and $Z=f(X,Y)$, where $f$ is some function, how can I show that:
$$
H(Z) \leq H(X,Y)
$$
With equality if the function $f$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W=(X,Y)$ such that $Z=f(W)$. Then, the mutual information between $W$ and $Z$ is:
$$
I(W;Z) = H(Z) - H(Z|W) = H(W) - H(W|Z)
$$
Since:
$$
H(Z|W)=H(f(W)|W)=0
$$
Then:
$$
H(Z) = H(W) - H(W|Z)
$$
Since $H(W|Z)$ is non-negative, then:
$$
H(Z) \leq H(W)
$$
If $f$ is invertible, which means that $H(W|Z)=H(f^{-1}(Z)|Z)=0$, then:
$$
H(Z) = H(W)
$$

Comment: Does the equality also imply that $f$ is invertible?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama A modified version of the converse is true: consider any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X = f(Y)$ and $H(X) = H(Y)$. Because $X = f(Y)$, then $H(X\mid Y) = 0$. Also, because $H(X) = H(Y)$, then $H(Y \mid X ) = H(X \mid Y) = 0$. Because $H(Y \mid X) = 0$, [then](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/443292/296197) there exists some function $g$ such that $Y = g(X) = g(f(Y))$. This implies that $f$ has a *left-inverse* $g$, which [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099699/652310) that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Actually, I’m not sure if the argument above holds, it may be the case that $g$ does not exist. The proof needs more work.

Comment: I think that the argument in the answer follows by noting that $H(X|Y) = 0$ if and only if there is function $f$ such that $X = f(Y)$.